# What's ending 'Attribute' in ActionFilterAttribute needed for when filter is being mapped without that word

Tags: c#, attributes

I've created a new mvc 4 project (razor engine) and I'm not sure of one thing.

There's a filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
...
}
```

and there's a controller using that filter:

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Why using **InitializeSimpleMembership** instead of **InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute** is working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[17.1.1 Attribute usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664613%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The example

```
[Simple] class Class1 {...}
[Simple] interface Interface1 {...}
```

> shows several uses of the Simple attribute. **Although this attribute is defined with the name SimpleAttribute, when this attribute is used, the Attribute suffix may be omitted**, resulting in the short name Simple. Thus, the example above is semantically equivalent  to the following:

```
[SimpleAttribute] class Class1 {...}
[SimpleAttribute] interface Interface1 {...}
```

Edit: For a extra clarity, in case you were wondering about the naming convention, [17.1 Attribute classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of Attribute. Uses of an attribute may either include or omit this suffix.